# GTK how to increase Grid cell width and height

Tags: c, gtk, gtk4

The following code creates a grid of cat icons, using the cat.jpg file below.

```
static void make_toggles(GtkWidget * window) {
    GtkWidget *stop_grid, vpaned;
    int i;
    stop_grid = gtk_grid_new();
    vpaned = gtk_paned_new(GTK_ORIENTATION_VERTICAL);
    int num_stops = 10;
    char label[7]; label[0] = '\0';
    for (i = 0; i < num_stops; i++) {
        sprintf(label, "%d", i);
        stop = gtk_toggle_button_new_with_label(label);
        image = gtk_image_new_from_file("cat.jpg");
        gtk_button_set_child(GTK_BUTTON(stop), image);
        gtk_grid_attach(GTK_GRID (stop_grid), stop, i % 5 , 1 + (i/5), 1, 1); 
        g_signal_connect(stop, "toggled", G_CALLBACK(stop_toggle), NULL);
    }
    gtk_grid_set_column_spacing(GTK_GRID(stop_grid), 10);
    gtk_grid_set_row_spacing(GTK_GRID(stop_grid), 10);
    gtk_paned_set_start_child(GTK_PANED(vpaned), stop_grid);
    gtk_paned_set_resize_start_child(GTK_PANED(vpaned), TRUE);
    gtk_window_set_child (GTK_WINDOW (window), vpaned);
}
```

This is called from the application activate handler:

```
static void activate (GtkApplication* app, gpointer user_data) {
    GtkWidget *window;

    window = gtk_application_window_new (app);
    gtk_window_set_title (GTK_WINDOW (window), "Left Panel");
    gtk_window_set_default_size (GTK_WINDOW (window), 700, 500);
    make_toggles(window);
    gtk_widget_show (window);
}
```

However, the icons are really tiny. Is there a way to increase the size of each individual cell so the cat can be seen more legibly?
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 1):

The cells in a `GtkGrid` will adjust to the size of their contents. So rather than fiddling around in GtkGrid, you want to take a look at those images.

In other words, if you want to make the images bigger, you want to use something like [`gtk_image_set_pixel_size()`](https://docs.gtk.org/gtk4/method.Image.set_pixel_size.html). Note that the default behavior of [`GtkImage`](https://docs.gtk.org/gtk4/class.Image.html) is to have an icon-like size, since that's what its intended to be used for. If you're really more interested in showing more general images, you might find the [`GtkPicture`](https://docs.gtk.org/gtk4/class.Picture.html) class to better suit your needs (for example, it will use the natural size of the image you're loading)

Answer (score 0):

While not really an answer, the Gtk FlowBox is a bit more flexible, as its children naturally fill out the existing space.